# Select Query is not working with in Clause

Tags: sql-server, no-response

Sql query is not working if we pass value In clause converted from 'Canada,Portugal' to  'Canada','Portugal'
 if pass hardcode value  In clause 'Canada','Portugal' it works

```
  declare @GeographicalLocation varchar(max) 
        set @GeographicalLocation ='Canada,Portugal'
        set @GeographicalLocation  = REPLACE(@GeographicalLocation, ',', ''',''')
        set @GeographicalLocation = ''''+@GeographicalLocation+'''';
select ContinentName from [ContinentList] where ContinentId in 
    (select ContinentId from [CountryList] where [CountryName] 
     in(@GeographicalLocation)and BaseId is Null)
```

Comment: you should try `split()` function and join with it.

Comment: Why it is not working ?

Comment: You're not passing in a list, you're passing in a single string containing the value `Canada,Portugal` and it's not possible to use strings in `in` clause

Answer (score 0):

Because, at the end your `where` clause looks like:

```
where [CountryName] in ('''Canada'',''Portugal''')
```

This string in `where` caluse should be two separate strings, but it's only one! It should look like this:

```
where [CountryName] in ('Canada','Portugal')
```

So, for this situation I'd use something like

```
where charindex([CountryName], @GeographicalLocation) > 0
```

In this approach, you don't need to append extra `'` to your string variable.
And I'd recommend using case sensitive collation.